# How can I keep track of changes in my site's view?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, cache

I want to keep track of changes in our company's website view. I want to know about changes to links and pictures in the homepage. I don't need to keep track of website's development, e.g I don't want a source control system. I have access to website's google analytics and webaster tools account.

To be more simplistic, maybe there is a way to see my website's cached version for any time I desire?!

Answer (score 2):

Try the Wayback Machine http://archive.org/web/, you can even take snapshots of the page when you want.